# Delete sit0 interface

Tags: wi-fi, kernel, android-12, ipv6

My samsung smartphone keeps losing network connection. Internet will work only when I restart the mobile. By default my custom Android 12 (rooted with magisk) use ipv4 routing table.

```
    ip route show 
    default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
    192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.3
```

ip a command shows two new interfaces:

```
    sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
           link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
    
    ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
           link/tunnel6 ::brd ::
```

I tried a few solutions to disable ipv6:

1. Disable ipv6 Magisk module
2. watch - n 1 /script.sh

```
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/autoconf
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/ip6tnl0/autoconf
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/accept_ra
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/disable_ipv6
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/accept_ra
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6
```

3. I droped ipv6 traffic in ip6tables.

But netstat still shows ipv6 traffic. Sometimes I see lot's of udp6 connections and get banned from google.

4. `ip tunnel del sit0`

I don't see any error, but sit0 interface still here.

I want to delete ipv6 tunnel and ipv6 module (or block it completely) from my system.

What else can I do?